# How to install Jira Plugin on Netbeans without access to the internet

Tags: netbeans, jira, netbeans6.7, netbeans-plugins

I am planning to install Jira plug-in for Netbeasns 6.7.1 on a set of workstations. Unfortunately, these workstations are not connected to internet, therefore I cannot use the Netbean’s plugin manager. Is it possible to get the plug-in from the internet and install them manually on the mentioned workstations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside my NetBeans on OSX, I can accomplish this by going to *Tools > Plugins* and then in the dialog box that comes up, select the *Downloaded* tab.

At the top, there's a button called *Add Plugins...* which pops open a File Chooser dialog box.  You'll need to have the `.nbm` file already downloaded (such as onto a thumb drive, or somewhere else that's accessible on the system you want to install the plugin on), navigate to that directory and select it.  Then it should install for you.

Comment: Where can you find the .nbm file for the Netbeans Jira plugin?

Comment: If you're connected to the internet, you can just grab it from the Netbeans Update Center.  Once it's downloaded onto your machine, I can't say where the .nbm file resides, but a search of your drive should find it.  From there, you could copy it onto a thumb drive for use on other machines.